# In Anaconda, RStudio bash does not find Git

Tags: git, bash, anaconda, rstudio, conda

- I have installed both RStudio v1.1.383 and Git 2.15.0 using the Anaconda platform on Windows 10.
- In RStudio global config, I have already provided the path to git.exe, provided a RSA key, checked "Enable version control interface for RStudio projects", and new terminals open with "Git bash".
- In project options, VCS is set to Git.
- I have successfully commited files to my local git, but I need to access the Shell to push them to GitHub.

The problem is: when I open RStudio's Shell, it doesn't find Git.

```
bash-4.3$ git
bash: git: command not found
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Git using the conda-forge version and now it works as expected.

```
conda install -c conda-forge git
```